# pandas hierarchical indexing unique values

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have series:

```
A  a  1
   b  1
B  c  5
   d  8
   e  5
```

where first two columns together is the hierarchical index. I want to find how many unique values are for index `level=0`, e.g., in this output should be `A 1; B 2`. How can this be done easily? Thanks!

Comment: Why does `B 2` mean?

Comment: sorry had a mistake in the question (just edited). A - 1 means there is only one unique value (5) , B - 2 values (5 and 8)

Comment: @hovo is this content of file???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on level 0 and then call [`.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html#pandas.Series.nunique) on the column:

```
>>> df
     val
A a    1
  b    1
B c    5
  d    8
  e    5
>>> df.groupby(level=0)['val'].nunique()
A    1
B    2
Name: val, dtype: int64
```